# Filter files on a s3 bucket based on the file name

Tags: awk, grep, ls, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket which has files named as such:

```
example_test_20200612010000   
example_test_20200612020000
example_test_20200612020000
example_control_20200612010000
example_control_20200612020000
example_control_20200612020000
```

Files as such come to this s3 bucket every few minutes - I need to identify which test files are new (that I haven't already processed). My logic was to do something like this:

```
aws s3 ls [s3 bucket name] --profile [profile name] | grep "test" | awk '$4 > 'example_test_20200612010000'
```

The file naming is always consistent so just checking for all test files in this bucket where the file name is lexicographically greater than the latest file I have processed (thus comparing that timestamp part at the end).

Answer (score 3):

try

```
| awk -v ref=example_test_20200612010000 '/test/ && $4 > ref { print $4}'
```

note that you can list objects by date (all in one line)

```
aws s3api list-object --bucket ... 
   --query 'Contents[?LastModified>`2020-05-01`].{Key: Key,Size: Size}'
```

replacing LastModified>`2020-05-01` of course.

to process the JSON result use

```
| jq -r '.[].Key'
```