# Using awk and local variable for filtering

Tags: awk, grep, ls

I have a command:

```
$var=test_file_20200612000000

aws s3 ls [s3 bucket name] --profile [profile name] | grep "test" | awk '$4 > $var'
```

This is looking at files on an s3 bucket and returning only those where the name is greater than a string variable being passed in (finding new files with later time stamps essentially). Awk is not recognizing the var variable - how does one deal with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a shell variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50044/use-a-shell-variable-in-awk)

Comment: welcome to U&L, please don't post twice the same question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592603/filter-files-on-a-s3-bucket-based-on-the-file-name